# Make sure GtkWindow fits all children

Tags: gtk3, gtkbuilder

How do I make sure my `GtkWindow` fits all children?

As you can see, currently my `GtkWindow` can shrink to the point the children do not fit in it.

[image]

I have been browsing the documentation, but there doesn't even seem to be a way to hard-code the minimum size, let alone let it dynamically depend on the size of my children.

The UI is written in XML and loaded using `GtkBuilder`.

Comment: Hi, which is the widget hierarchy? You can set a minimum widget size with Gtk's Widget [`set_size_request`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html#gtk-widget-set-size-request) function/method.

Comment: @JoséFonte I have a ApplicationWindow <- Stack <- Paned

Comment: Which language are you using? Did you use glade to design the UI? Check Gtk's Paned  child widget shrink/resize flags. That's your solution/answer.

Comment: @JoséFonte Is there also a way to scale automatically?

Comment: it depends on what you mean with scale automatically. You want the entry boxes to grow if the container grows? The sidebar already expands so i think you meant the entries. Set Gtk EntryBox Horizontal expand flag as ON/TRUE.

Comment: @JoséFonte As you can see in the screenshot, the entries are at their minimum size, but the window doesn't fit them.

Comment: Are you using glade or are you setting up the UI programmatically? If the last, which language are you using? Can you add part of the code where you setup the UI. There are many approaches... Please add more details to your question. Thanks

Comment: @JoséFonte Added the requested information to the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158869/discussion-between-jose-fonte-and-jeroen-bollen).

Answer (score 1):

As @JoséFonte pointed out in the comments, I had to disable shrinking for all children of my `GtkPaned`.

To achieve this I used Glade, and then for each child opened its properties, went to the packing tab, and disabled `Shrink`.

[image]